# Date and time Query - problem

Tags: sql-server-2008

I try to run this query:

```
select * from WorkTbl
where ((Tdate >= '20100414' AND Ttime >= '06:00')  and (Tdate <= '20100415' AND Ttime <= '06:00'))
```

I have this date: 14/04/2010 and time: 14:00

I cant see hem, how to fix the query?

Thank's in advance

Comment: What are the data types in TDate and TTime?  Are they date/time fields or string fields?

Comment: Agree with Brian, please post the sql used to create your table.  You can right click on the table and select "script to..." to have SSMS generate it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried formatting the date in the where clause like this:

```
'DD/MM/YYYY'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current query will only match rows where `Ttime` is exactly `06:00` (ie, this is the only time that matches both the `>= '06:00'` and the `<= '06:00` criteria).

Try something like this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM WorkTbl
WHERE (Tdate = '20100414' AND Ttime >= '06:00')
    OR (Tdate = '20100415' AND Ttime <= '06:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM WorkTbl
WHERE (Tdate > '20100414' OR (Tdate == '20100414' AND Ttime >= '06:00'))
  AND (Tdate < '20100415' OR (Tdate == '20100415' AND Ttime <= '06:00'))
```